# changing href attribute value on each click on it from an array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have this normal link

```
<a href='#'>Click Me</a>
```

And i have an array like the following

```
$values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$first = current($values);
```

What i'm trying to do is that on each click on the **link**, The attribute value changes to the *next in array* value from a to b to c to d then to **a** again if it is the **end**,
depending on a get request **`$_GET['order'];`**
 How can i achieve that using **JQuery** or **PHP**.

What i've tried to do is

```
$current = $_GET['order'];
if(isset($current)){
    if(in_array($current, $values)){
        $link = next($values);
        echo "<a href='$link'>Click Me</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='$first'>Click Me</a>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<a href='$first'>Click Me</a>";
}
```

if `$_GET['order'] == 'a';` the `$link` would change to be `<a href='b'>Click Me</a>` and on and on.

Comment: If you click the `a` then surely you're not on the same page anymore, so changing the `href` is moot...? Seeing some more of your code would help a lot here

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan added my code.

Comment: You'll need a form with an input named `order` to submit those values

Comment: @adeneo I don't want to submit it, But just changing the link attribute value on each new `$_GET` value to the next value and `loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery for this (read comments for explanation):

```
var values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

//We need to get the value of our $_GET['order'], let's parse our current location url
var get_vars = [];
location.search.replace('?', '').split('&').forEach(function(pair){
    pair_arr = pair.split("=", 2);
    get_vars[pair_arr[0]] = pair_arr[1];
});

//Now let's init the curent index equal to our $_GET['order'] (TODO: error checking/handleing)
var cur_index = values.indexOf(get_vars['order']);

//Now let's init the link value
$('#link').attr('href', '?order='+values[cur_index]);


$('#link').on('click', function(){
    if(cur_index + 1 >= values.length){
        cur_index = 0;
    }else{
        cur_index++;
    }
    $(this).attr('href', '?order='+values[cur_index]);
});
```

And in the html, you of course will need to give your link an ID:

```
<a href='#' id="link">Click Me</a>
```

And in PHP.. or in your url... you will need to supply a GET var:

```
<?php
/* TEST */
$_GET['order'] = 'a';
?>
```

NOTE: this link will never actually take you anywhere... it will only update the GET variable... it will have to be modified in order to actually do something more useful.